# PIC18f46K40 Datasheet/MCC discrepancy

Tags: pic, datasheet, microchip

I have found a problem with the PIC18f46K40 datasheet or a problem in MCC - I am using the 44-pin TQFP package.

In the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/40001816E-1314271.pdf), the pin layout for the PIC18f46K40 is given below:
[image]

The MCC (MPLABX IDE v4.15) pin layout is given below:
[image]

The **NC pins** are not consistent. Which layout do I use in my design?

I have a strong feeling the MCC pin layout is right and the datasheet is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: You're referring to an out-of-date (and incorrect) datasheet. The latest one is [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18LF26-45-46K40-Data-Sheet-DS40001816F.pdf), and appears to match what you're seeing in the MCC.

Answer (score 0):

This fail is collected on the PIC18F46K40 errata sheet.
You can find it [here](http://media.futureelectronics.com/PCN/56890_SPCN.PDF) (page 6). Best regards.